# Latest Activity on Account if Assigned to user is not User B

Tags: visual-workflow, formula-field, account, activities

I'm trying to see if it's possible to create something that will show me the most recent activity on the Account. Currently we are using a custom field that references the LastActivityDate field and we followed this
traffic light solution.

https://focusonforce.com/configuration/how-to-display-a-traffic-light-indicator-in-salesforce/

However I want to make a slight change

I want to show the latest activity BUT if its been assigned to User B then show the previous activity that is not User B. From what I know its not possible on a formula field but thought I'd ask in case someone has an idea or know if it's possible or can give me a better solution.

As I wasn't able to create anything on the account that would work I was able to create a report (see below) which will show all Accounts with/without activities. However would be better if end user can see a field on the account which shows recent activity which would be more ideal. I have provided my formula for the Activity Age field below as well. I can't use LastActivityDate on the Task field so next best thing was to use CreatedDate.

[image]

```
IF(
OR(
Owner:User.FirstName = "B2BMA",
Owner:User.FirstName = "Integration"
),
"Not Valid Activity",



IF(
AND(TODAY() < (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 30)
),
"Less than 1 Month Old",
IF(
AND(TODAY() > (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 30),
TODAY() < (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 60)
),
"2 Months Old",
IF(
AND(TODAY() > (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 60),
TODAY() < (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) + 90)
),
"3 Months Old",
"Greater than 3 Months Old"
)
)
)

)
```

I was thinking I could create a flow to trigger on the Task and modify a custom field on the account however it will only work for future tasks and not the older activity records that are already created.

Anyone with a solution or better idea on how I'd be able to do what we want to do?

Thank you